# How to run DDL in Access 2013?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ddl

I need to run DDL script to create tables to import data into Microsoft Access. I have the DDL script already made and it has worked in Oracle SQL Developer already, but I'm looking to do it in Access as well.

I can't seem to find an easy way to do it. It looks like previous versions of Access had this feature.

Comment: What error are you getting? DDL is a part of Access.

Comment: Be aware that DDL written for Oracle SQL will almost certainly require some tweaking before it will work with Access SQL.

Comment: Also, Access will only execute one DDL statement at a time.  So if your script includes multiple statements, you'll have to break out each one, translate it to Access SQL, and execute it.  You can't give Access multiple statements to execute as a single batch.

Comment: If the Oracle tables exist, it should be easier to create a DSN to the Oracle database, and import those tables (with or without the data they contain) into Access.

Answer (score 8):

Probably the easiest way to run a DDL statement in Access 2013 is to choose

CREATE > Query Design

from the ribbon, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to dismiss the "Show Tables" dialog, click the "Data Definition" button on the ribbon

[image: DDL.png]

type or copy the DDL statement into the query pane, then click the "Run" button on the ribbon (big red exclamation point).

Comment: With this concept, it is possible to create an Access query object that will modify the database schema.  I've got a Make Table query that after use can now be followed by a DDL query to `DROP TABLE tmp_Data`.